# Specifying Role in ASK CLI v2

Tags: amazon-iam, alexa-skills-kit

I'm setting a new skill with ASK CLI V2 in Alexa. I would like to specify a specific role when deploying the new skill instead of letting the command create a new one.

Some background: I created a new skill using the `new` command and used the `hello world` template. Then, I ran the `deploy` command. I am using a corporate account and I don't have permissions to create a new role. I have to use an existing one.

AccessDenied: User: [...] is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::845692260290:role/ask-lambda-skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you need to ask your organization to give some permissions to your user to create Lambda Execution Roles, as per the documentation [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html)

AWS permissions

When ASK CLI creates a new Lambda function, it associates the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole with the function. For more information, see Manage Permissions: Using an IAM Role (Execution Role) in the AWS Lambda documentation. Make sure the AWS credentials that you configured for use with ASK CLI have permission to create IAM roles and associate permissions.

I hope this helps.